# Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error in springboot Rest API

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, socketexception, connection-reset

I have a springboot application with one Rest API. In that REST API, I am invoking another REST API (3rd party). I am connecting to it via RestTemplate something like below,

```html
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
            .build();
}
```

Technically it working fine but sometimes, I am getting "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset " like 1 in 100 calls. Not able to understand why it is happening.
Can anybody help to find the root cause and permanent fix for the same?